# Error on uploading CSV File in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

Hi I am trying to import an CSV into MYSQL database using A CI Library. But I get this error in Controller that file type is now allowed

Controller:

```
    <?php

     class Csv extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('csv_model');
        $this->load->library('csvimport');
    }

    function index() {
        $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    }

    function importcsv() {
        $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
        $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        // If upload failed, display error
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        } else {
            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $file_path =  './uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

            if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
                $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
                foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                    $insert_data = array(
                        'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],
                        'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],
                        'phone'=>$row['phone'],
                        'email'=>$row['email'],
                    );
                    $this->csv_model->insert_csv($insert_data);
                }
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
                redirect(base_url().'csv');
                //echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);
            } else 
                $data['error'] = "Error occured";
                $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
            }

        } 

   }
   /*END OF FILE*/
```

The Model :

```
    <?php

    class Csv_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function get_addressbook() {     
        $query = $this->db->get('addressbook');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function insert_csv($data) {
        $this->db->insert('addressbook', $data);
    }
  }
     /*END OF FILE*/
```

I am trying to Import A CSV using PHP Codeigniter. Now I am getting an error that

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

So as you can see i have kept the allowed file type = csv then also this issue is coming. So please help. Thanks

Comment: **config/mimes.php** you should add `text/plain` in csv key

Comment: @Abdulla What type of key ?

Comment: search with csc. may be top of file

Comment: didnt understand your point @Abdulla

Comment: go to file and search **csv** in **config/mimes.php** file and add `text/plain` in end of line

Comment: its already in there 'csv' => array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel','text/plain'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the mime type you can go with the CALLBACK function
This will add more portability too...

```
 function importcsv() {

        $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
        $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('uploaded_file','Uploaded file', 'trim|callback_chk_attachment');

        if($this->form_validation->run()){    
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        // If upload failed, display error
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        } else {
            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $file_path =  './uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

            if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
                $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
                foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                    $insert_data = array(
                        'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],
                        'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],
                        'phone'=>$row['phone'],
                        'email'=>$row['email'],
                    );
                    $this->csv_model->insert_csv($insert_data);
                }
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
                redirect(base_url().'csv');
                //echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);
            } else 
                $data['error'] = "Error occured";
                $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
            }

        }




Call Back function for File Upload validation:

        public function chk_attachment() // callback validation for check the attachment extension
        {
            $file_type = array('.csv');
            if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']))
            {
                $ext = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'],"."));
                if(in_array($ext,$ext_array))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('chk_attachment','Attachment allowed only csv');
                    return false;
                }
            }
            {
               $this->form_validation->set_message('chk_attachment','image field is required');
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: still getting an error The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: I also had that problem. But this call back fixed me!
Anyway I will find other solutions.

Comment: i just used your code @blacmoon but did'nt show any diffrence :(